# How does Ultron appear to use "enhanced powers" when he shouldn't have any?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron

In Korea, Black Widow chases after the truck carrying Ultron and Captain America on her on her motorbike. At one point, Ultron fends her off and forces her to break off pursuit by

> lifting a large a chunk of the street mound of dirt in front of her.

How does Ultron manage to do this, since he is a machine with no other special powers?

Comment: I'm disappointed the spoiler tags don't contain *How does Ultron* "Gangnam Style?"

Comment: Um... he's a robot with the Iron Man suit as a prototype. Why wouldn't you expect him to be able to do all sorts of amazing things?

Comment: @Smithers Not that it matters, but his physical body was actually a HYDRA prototype, which he uploaded into after the Avengers destroyed his banged-up initial form.  But either way, the point remains: super-high-tech robot.

Answer (score 15):

> I believe he is shown to have some kind of super-magnet in the back of his hand. When they first encounter each other at Ulysses klaws shipyard, Ultron activates this magnet & pulls Tony towards him.
>  [image: Ultron activates the magnet]
>  
> Also, these days [several roads have a component of steel](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=are%20roads%20built%20on%20metal%20surface&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=J2BEVabdFYHbuQTGsIDIDA#q=steel%20in%20road%20making). If the super-magnet can pull the Iron Man suit like it were made of paper, not surprising that it could rip up a piece of pavement.

Comment: No downvote, but magnets don't glow. Then again, Captain America's gauntlet magnets appeared to light up blue when he called his shield, so who knows.

Comment: It's a movie mechanism to show that something is working. And whoever downvoted this please let me know why you don't think this answer is correct.

Comment: @Omegacron: “magnets don’t glow”. [*Au contraire!*](http://www.zazzle.co.uk/glowing+magnets)

Comment: Well we do know Ultron also is a total showoff :P

Comment: @PaulD.Waite lol well technically in those cases, it's not the magnets glowing, but a substance or light ON the magnet.

Comment: @Omegacron: maybe Ultron has that on his magnets too.

Answer (score 6):

**Despite appearances, Ultron has a veritable cornucopia of powers available to him.**

Although the movie version of [Ultron](http://marvel.wikia.com/Ultron_(Earth-616)) only used limited powers while on-screen, it's definitely not accurate to say that Ultron has no "special powers". In the comics, he has had the following technology & abilities:

- Superhuman strength *
- Superhuman durability *
- Superhuman speed
- Genius intellect *
- Self-repair/healing abilities *
- An understanding of technology which surpasses that of Tony Stark *
- Concussive blasts/repulsors *
- Supersonic flight capability
- Force field technology *
- Limited telekinesis
- Limited shape-shifting ability
- Mind control
- The ability to "hack" into any computer system *
- The ability to upload his consciousness into any computer system *
- The ability to change bodies as needed *

I've placed an asterisk beside the abilities we see on-screen in [**Age of Ultron**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers:_Age_of_Ultron).

The most likely method for moving any object would be telekinesis, but if that's the case it certainly could have been called out more. As it is, we are never told that the MCU Ultron has that ability. Rather, he makes a gesture, his hand glows, and the chunk of road is moved upward. This could simply be a clever use of force fields, but it could just as easily be a form of telekinesis. In fact, he used something similar

> to pull Iron Man towards him during the confrontation at Klaw's mine.

*In the image below, the comics version of Ultron utilizes both his shape-shifting AND telekinesis abilities to re-shape his form:*

[image: Image from the comics where Ultron utilizes both his shape-shifting AND telekinesis abilities to re-shape his form]

Comment: He has some sort of force field capability as well.  It's where HYDRA got that tech.

Comment: after watching the movie it also could have been some form of burst or shockwave sent from ultron into the ground that bounced the ground up .

Comment: I think the film pretty firmly establishes that Ultron does not have all the powers of the comic, so this answer seems kind of irrelevant.

Comment: @DogeTheExplorer : Actually, even though the powers are never explained on-screen, he is seen using most of these in the movie.

Comment: That's because most of those powers directly mirror what Stark's suit can do. He certainly never displays shape-shifting or mind control

Comment: Feel free to downvote the answer if you don't agree, but as far as I'm concerned we see 3/4 of the listed powers on-screen in AoU. It's not much of a stretch to assume he has the others as well.

Comment: I feel the answer is too generic, and doesn't adhere quite to what is actually shown in the movie. Please have a look at my speculation in the answer below.

Answer (score -2):

During the climax, Friday tells Iron Man that the city is being held together through artificial gravity. This means that Ultron learned how to manipulate gravity and this could be the answer. It could also explain why Vision can fly without any visible propulsion; he can  manipulate gravity, too.

Comment: Mmmm. The artificial gravity is a function of the vibranium in the city (probably explained away through superconductivity or something), IIRC. That could certainly explain how Ultron could fly *later*, but I believe he flies before he has any Vibranium in his body. Either way, wouldn’t really explain how he lifts the street, which does not seem to have any vibranium.